# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado Python

Tags: python, permisos

Estoy creando un codigo para la escuela el cual trata de en de borrar los iconos del escritorio, pero al ejecutarlo da el siguiente error "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado"
El codigo es el siguiente:

```
def delete_files():
destkop_path = "C:\\Users\\" + os.getlogin() + "\\Desktop"
with os.scandir(destkop_path) as icons:
    for icon in icons:
        os.remove(icon)
```

Comment: ¿Has probado correr el script como usuario con privilegios? (Botón derecho sobre el icono de `cmd` -> Ejecutar como administrador)

Comment: Probe hacerlo pero me devuelve el mismo error al ejecutarlo como .exe y con permisos de administrador

Comment: Prueba lo que se responde en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script), tu script necesita permisos elevados, para ello debes interactuar con la API de Windows.